# numPy logic function over an array

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

I'm trying to generate a vector `[a(1), a(2),...a(100)]` where `a(i)` is `sin(i)` if `sin(i)>0`, and `0` otherwise. What I came up with is creating a lambda expression and applying it through `numpy.fromfunction`, as such: `np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: sin(j) if np.sin(j) > 0 else 0, (1, 100), dtype=int)` , but this produces an error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I get around that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case, you can use `np.maximum(np.sin(range(100)), np.zeros(100))`

More generally use [np.where()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create an array based on a comparison of 2 arrays:

```
b = np.sin(range(100))
c = np.zeros(100)
a = np.where(b > c, b, 0)
```

or, in your case,

```
b = np.sin(range(100))
a = np.where(b > 0, b, 0)
```

(no need to create `c`)

Edit: though where() allows for more complex allocations, it seems to be slower:

```
%timeit a = np.where(b > 0, b, 0)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.15 µs per loop

%timeit b[b<0] = 0
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 µs per loop
```

Comment: you don't have to create zeros array , comparing using `np.where( b > 0 , b , 0)` is enough

Comment: Yes I just noticed that and editted. Thanks for the improvment.

Comment: @NaderHisham I'm keeping this sample to illustrate the fact that np.where works with 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Use array masking:

```
a = np.arange(1, 101)
b = np.sin(a)
b[b<0] = 0
```